# Changing an executable file's icon permanently

Tags: icons

I have created an icon for an executable program I wrote. I can change the icon locally, but anytime I edit the program, it changes itself back to the default executable file icon. I need the icon I created to stay so when my coworkers clone my git repository, the icon is applied to the executable file. How do I manage this?

Comment: That seems unrelated to git.

Comment: you need [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/)...

Comment: @Aaron I'm currently searching for an OS X equivalent.

Comment: @jagdpanzer my bad... are you packaging your app as just a binary file or as a .app container?

Comment: @Aaron Right now it's just an executable file. I should close this question and do research on packaging it as an app?

Comment: @jagdpanzer yes, I've never bundled an app myself, but you'll probably want (need) to do it with xcode :/ (not my favorite editor by far..) [here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW19) something I found real quick to maybe get started